# How to prove that if $p^k$ divides a finite group $G$ there exists a strict subgroup $p^k||H|$ or $p|Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given a finite group $G$ and a prime $p$ such that $p^k| |G|$. Now prove that there exists a strict subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $p^k | |H| $ or $p| |Z(G)|$.

Well, I know what you're thinking: just use Sylow's first theorem and voilà.
But this proposition is part of a (guided) proof of Sylow's theorem I'm trying to make...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are the previous step(s) of your guided proof?

Comment: This is the first one :s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [class equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Conjugacy_class_equation) $$|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum |G : C_G(g_i)|,$$ for $g_i$ a set of representatives for nontrivial conjugacy classes of $G$. If $p^k \mid |G|$ but $p \not\mid |Z(G)|$, then there exists $g_i$ such that $$p \not\mid |G:C_G(g_i)| = \frac{|G|}{|C_G(g_i)|}.$$ If this were not so, then $$p \mid \left ( |G| - \sum_i |G:C_G(g_i)| \right) = |Z(G)|,$$ a contradiction. Therefore the denominator $|C_G(g_i)|$ has absorbed the factor $p^k$, so $p^k \mid |C_G(g_i)|$.

Comment: But how does this proof that there exists a subgroup $H$ such that $p^k | H$. It seems to me that you have shown that if $p^k | |G|$ and not $p^k | |Z(G)|$ there exists a subgroup $H$ such that $p ||H|$

Comment: Whoops! I fixed it.

Comment: Yep, that's it!